# How can I create a login program that checks for availability on Python?

Tags: python, authentication

I'm making a user login for a little project I'm working on at school, practising my file handling and whatnot. For the most part, it's going fine, but I'm having trouble when I try and create new users. The new user needs to have an original username and password to be created, otherwise, it should tell them that their choice is unavailable. For some reason, it works fine with the first username and password in the files and makes the user retry. But when I try and create a new user with a name that I know I shouldn't be able to, it lets me.

```
def signUp():
    username = str(input("\nPlease enter your new username "))
    file = open ("usernames.txt","r")
    for x in file:
        if username in x:
            print ("\nThat username is already in use, please try another")
            signUp()
        else:
            print ("Your username is now ",username)
    file.close()
    
    password = input("\nPlease create a password ")
    file = open ("passwords.txt","r")
    for x in file:
        if password in x:
            print ("\nThat password is already in use, please try another")
            signUp()
        else:
            print ("Your password is now ", password," Don't forget it")
    file.close()   

    file = open ("usernames.txt","a")
    file.write (username)
    file.write ("\n")
    file.close()

    file = open ("passwords.txt","a")
    file.write (password)
    file.write ("\n")
    file.close()
    
    print ("\nYour login details have been saved")
    print ("Please login")
    logIn()
```

In the username file, it has the names:

> Alex
>
> Josh

The password file has:

> 123qwe
>
> ewq321

The code works for Alex and 123qwe and stops them from being repeated, but not for Josh or ewq321.
At the moment, I'm not looking for any other improvements. I'll refine it all later. For now, I just need help with this little predicament. I understand that my explanation is a little confusing, so it might help to copy what I've already done and play around with it. Obviously, this isn't the whole code, so it might not make perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in both loops, exactly on the `else` clause.
Your code checks that if the only first username already exists that's because you introduced an else on the loop, and also you need to get out of the program if the username already exists using `return`.

Here is the new code:

```
def signUp():
    username = str(input("\nPlease enter your new username "))
    file = open ("usernames.txt","r")
    for x in file:
        if username in x:
            print ("\nThat username is already in use, please try another")
            signUp()
            return

    print ("Your username is now ",username)
    file.close()

    password = input("\nPlease create a password ")
    file = open ("passwords.txt","r")
    for x in file:
        if password in x:
            print ("\nThat password is already in use, please try another")
            signUp()
            return

    print ("Your password is now ", password," Don't forget it")
    file.close()   

    file = open ("usernames.txt","a")
    file.write (username)
    file.write ("\n")
    file.close()

    file = open ("passwords.txt","a")
    file.write (password)
    file.write ("\n")
    file.close()

    print ("\nYour login details have been saved")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess it just needed a new pair of eyes to spot a mistake that I hadn’t. I copied the code from somewhere else in my program and expected it to work, but I suppose I didn’t think it through enough.